# How do I find my Keys?

Tags: fable-3

So I've been collecting keys in Fable 3 and I missing some number of golden ones.  I know where they should be I just don't know how many I have.

Is there some way I can see how many golden keys I have?

Comment: Ignoring the tag, I'd say, it's always either under the mat or in the plant pot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a total count in one location, no, I don't think there is any way to see the total count that you have. They left out a total count for silver keys as well that's easy to access in the new *menu*.

You can view the map in the Sanctuary and hover over a location to see if you've received the golden key for each individual open location as it will show you either 0/0 if there's no key there, 0/1 if you haven't found the key, or 1/1 if you have found the golden key there. This only works for locations that you have opened through the quest so when you start out you'll only see just a few locations.